# XAMPP tem o mysql ativo?

Tags: xampp, wamp

Bom queria saber se o **XAMPP** tem o `mysql` ativo. Ou se está obsoleto igual à o **wamp**

Comment: ativo você quer dizer mysql na última versão? nesse link https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html tem a informação do mysql 5.6.24

Comment: Sim, na ultima versão no xampp se é possível utilizar o mysql ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, o Mysql tem como estável 5.6.12 (3 de junho de 2013)

o Xampp tem a 5.6.24

E temos em teste no Mysql 5.7.1 (23 de abril de 2013)

Comment: Então, não é possível utilizar mais o mysql, apenas o mysqli ?

Comment: Man, o xampp tem uma versão com "correções" da versão estável, pode ser sim usado perfeitamente!

Comment: Tendi, Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: ref. a dúvida do "mysqli", da uma lida nesse link http://pt.wingwit.com/P/php-mysql-programming/91958.html#.VVnKSflViko